# Run PHP for longer time in separate processes

Tags: php, performance, laravel, csv

I have a directory which can contain CSV files that come through a service that I need to import into database. These CSV files are 1000 rows each and can be 10 to 150 files.

I want to insert data of all these CSV files into database. The problem is that PHP dies because of timeout issue because even if I use `set_time_limit(0)`, the server (siteground.com) imposes its restrictions. Here is the code:

```
// just in case even though console script should not have problem
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_input_time', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function getRow()
{
    $files = glob('someFolder/*.csv');

    foreach ($files as $csvFile) {
        $fh = fopen($csvFile, 'r');

        $count = 0;
        while ($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
            $count++;

            // skip header
            if ($count === 1) {
                continue;
            }

            // make sure count of header and actual row is same
            if (count($this->headerRow) !== count($row)) {
                continue;
            }

            $rowWithHeader = array_combine($this->headerRow, $row);

            yield $rowWithHeader;
        }
    }
}

foreach(getRow() as $row) {
   // fix row
   // now insert in database
}
```

This is actually a Command run through `artisan` (I am using Laravel). I know that CLI doesn't have time restrictions but for some reason not all CSV files get imported and process ends at certain point of time.

So my question is is there way to invoke separate PHP process for each CSV file present in a directory ? Or some other way of doing this so I am able to import all CSV files without any issue like PHP's `generator,` etc

Comment: If the hosting provider wants that a script only runs for a limited time, then he can do that. Even running PHP through CLI won't help. He can just kill the process.

Comment: Why don't you run PHP script from localhost while connected to remote db? Locally you can set no time limit for your script.

Comment: @RobertTrzebiński: It has to run on server actually.

Comment: Shame, so you need to process one file at the time, or change hosting plan if this is not enough.

Comment: Keep in mind: You can set a timeout in the Webserver (nginx, Apache) or PHP pool (fpm, fastcgi) thats going to kill PHP, too, if it takes too long to run. It's not only php.ini if you don't run through `cli`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to process a limited number of files per one php process. For example, you can start with 10(calculate a number of files empirical) files, process them, mark as removed(move to a folder with processed file) and stop the process. After that start a new process to import another 10 files and so on. In Laravel you can say to not start more than one process for a specific command if another process is working already. The command for Laravel is below:

```
$schedule->command("your job")->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
```

If you use this approach you can be sure that all files will be processed for specific time and they will not consume too much resources to be killed.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do some bash magic. refactor your script so that it processes one file only. The file to process is an argument to the script, access it by using [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php).

```
<?php
// just in case even though console script should not have problem
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_input_time', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
$file = $argv[1]; // file is the first and only argument to the script
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function getRow($csvFile)
{
    $fh = fopen($csvFile, 'r');

    $count = 0;
    while ($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
        $count++;

        // skip header
        if ($count === 1) {
            continue;
        }

        // make sure count of header and actual row is same
        if (count($this->headerRow) !== count($row)) {
            continue;
        }

        $rowWithHeader = array_combine($this->headerRow, $row);

        yield $rowWithHeader;
    }
}

foreach(getRow($file) as $row) {
   // fix row
   // now insert in database
}
```

Now, call your script like this:

```
for file in `ls /path/to/folder | grep csv`; do php /path/to/your/script.php /path/to/folder/$file; done
```

This will execute your script for each `.csv` file in your `/path/to/folder`

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting providers allows cron jobs, they dont have a timeout limit.

Also they should fit the job better than manually calling the function for heavy and long tasks, since that could case huge problems if the method its called several times.